# Antonyms for SUBSPACE

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, terminology

What would the antonym of subspace be? May I call it a superspace/ parent space?

Specifically, say I have a space $S=\mathcal{R}^3$, and another space $O=\mathcal{R}^2$. I would like to "concatenate"/"combine" two spaces to be another concatenated space $P=concat[S,O]=\{S,O\}=\mathcal{R}^5$. How do I refer $P$ to $S$ and $O$? Is this even mathematically correct if I say that ''I concatenate space $S$ and space $O$ into a superspace $P=\{S,O\}$''?

Comment: The antonym could be "ambient space". However, in the case of concatenation, you might be interested in looking at the "(external) direct sum of vector spaces".

Comment: @AryamanMaithani Exact what I needed. Many thanks! Would you be happy to write this 
 comment as an answer? Also may I ask what is the difference between `external direct sum` and `Cartesian Product` in this case (real spaces)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The antonym could be "ambient space". However, in the case of concatenation, you might be interested in looking at the "(external) direct sum of vector spaces".

You also ask the difference between "external direct sum" and "Cartesian product". The Cartesian product is actually called the "direct product". For finitely many spaces, the direct product and direct sum are the same.

However, if you have an infinite collection of vector spaces, then the two are not generally the same.

---

More precisely: given a collection $\{V_i\}_{i \in I}$ of vector spaces, the direct product is the vector space which is equal to the cartesian product $\prod_{i \in I} V_i$ as a set and the operations are coordinate-wise.

However, the direct sum $\bigoplus_{i \in I} V_i$ is a subspace of the direct product consisting of those elements which have all but finitely many coordinates equal to $0$.

If $I$ is finite, then the two are the same.